# Concatenate strings by date in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, nosql

Is it possible to concatenate strings in mongoDB? I know you can aggregate numbers and sum them up, with the pipeline and aggregation methods.

My data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5992fa4bb3e6f523d0d23d19"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-08-14T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "text" : "Hello this is some testdata."
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5992fa4bb3e6f523d0d23d1a"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-08-14T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "text" : "This is some more testdata..."
}
```

Is it possible to concatenate the 'text' field by month?

The desired output for 2017-08 for e.g would be the text field in the first object concatenated with the text field in the second object.

Comment: What are you expecting by *"aggregated with the text field in the second object"*? Do you mean "concatenated"? Do you mean first? Do you mean in an array? Its really not clear what you mean because "aggregated" really does not do anything, other than being a general verb.

Comment: Okay. I mean the two text fields concatenated. new_string = Hello this is some testdata.This is some more testdata..."

Comment: I really don't see the practicality of that, and seemingly most designers would agree. The aggregation framework could only do this by first accumulating all the fields from each document within an array, and then concatenating the contents later. Pretty much the same for mapReduce, though technically without the BSON limit restriction on accumulation, but still on the output.

Comment: My approach might be wrong, but the desired output would in my case be a text string with all text fields per month concatenated. Is this possible?